Geometry Nodes Face Extrude height based on lightness value not working properly
Please see attached JPG. The extrude heights don't correspond to the lightness values that are generating the extrude value. How do I set this up so that the 75% brightness value generates an extrude height that is 75% of the total extrude height and so on. Thanks.

Here is the test PNG (its small 8x8 pixels (uses closest interpolation):

This is what the test.png image looks like in photoshop:


pls provide blend file because we have no idea how your test.png looks like. thx.

file is attached.

I think it would be a good idea to repost the .blend with the texture-image packed.

Had to google how to package a blend file! - I've attached it now.

The blend file (corrected packed.blend) attached to this question is the corrected version.

When I open your file in Photoshop myself, even PS does not show 100%, 75%, 50%, 25% for the greyscale values. It shows 100%, 72%, 47% and 23%. So on the one hand the issue has something to do with the color management in Photoshop how it saves the images. I guess it uses some sRGB or Adobe RGB conversions and/or gamma correction (sorry I'm no expert in this).
The other thing is, when you open the image file in Blender, you have to set the Color Space to Non-Color or Linear Rec.709 to get a better result. You can do this either in the Image Texture node in the Shader Editor or in the sidepanel of the Image Editor (the texture node in Geometry Node does not have this setting). The Color Space you set in any of these editors will be used throughout for this image.

But the even better solution would be to create the file again in Photoshop with the correct values (since the PNG has changed values after re-opening) and not save it as PNG, but a TIF file and in the save options disable the color profile. If you then open this file in Blender and set the Color Space to one of the previously mentioned options, you will get the closest result.
Sorry, this screenshot is from my German version of PS and apart from the language this might differ in different editions:

With this TIF file I got these values in Blender: 1.000, 0.744, 0.496 and 0.258 which is almost there. Maybe there are even better settings which I haven't found yet. If the extrusion is still not exactly like those values, the problem could be that Geometry Nodes places values on geometry, i.e. vertices etc. so it might be that the height is a bit decreased by the surrounding black areas.
By the way: Even with the TIF file Photoshop itself seems to change the values a bit. Re-opening the TIF file showed brightness values of 100%, 75%, 50% 25% correctly, but while the 50% brightness was RGB (128, 128, 128) or #808080 upon saving, it was now RGB (127, 127, 127) or #7F7F7F.

If, as you show, the packed  image is read as 'Non-Color' I'm getting this accuracy: https://imgur.com/a/4NvgWSq

@RobinBetts Hmmm... not when I checked it today ‍♂️ And Photoshop agreed that the values are further off...

How strange... I wonder why.. let's see how it goes for JK

it does work as it should work, but your image is a bit "complicated".

As you can see, if i plugin the color directly, i can change the height by changing the color.
Your image (black and orange) or course isn't 25% or 100% because 100% would be full white. So you should change your image to get a clear result what you wanna have.

update:
your color values in your image aren't right. Make sure the "value" is 0.75 for 75%. Same  0.25 for 25%. You can check that values with color picker as i did here:
https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/value%20not%20right.gif
sorry for using links here, but gif upload doesn't work once again.

Sorry, but I'm not using direct colour input, I'm using a small 8x8px PNG called test.png. It's attached to the original question.

i know, but use an image with "clear" colors like pure white and just change the value so that you can see that it works. You have used orange, which isn't 25% or 50%.

why should an image with some orange points on it give you 25/50/75%?

Sorry, but there is no orange in my image. It the test.png file attached to the question. It's a 8 x 8 pixel grayscale PNG. there is no orange.

then i would recommend downloading the blend file you uploaded in your question and check that out. There IS an orange/black image. Maybe you uploaded the wrong file? that's how your file is looking: [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/j08BiAFd.png

gosh I don't know what's happening then, it all loads fine on my side - no orange in the test.png :-(

ah ok, you didn't pack resources, i assume ;) now it worked

i updated my answer.

Thanks Chris. I took the test.png into photoshop and set the whites to 0%K, the black to 100%K and the three shades to 25%K, 50%K and 75%K. I took that new PNG into the blend file and it was a better result. I say better because it was accurate but on a log scale. I don't know why Geo Nodes interprets the values in this way? Anyhow, I fixed the issue with a math node set to Power (exp = 0.5) positioned between the Image Texture and Extrude Mesh nodes. Thanks for your help.

unfortunately i have no photoshop (knowledge) so i cannot say anything to that. I just can say that the png had the wrong values, as i showed in the gif. And i don't think Blender does this on a log scale. It takes the "value" which you see if you are using the eyedropper tool in blender.
